# A font rendering suddenly got strange in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, internet-explorer-11

I'm using a font called 'Note Sans KR', but the font rendering suddenly got strange in IE.

```
<input type="text" value="abc"> <input type="text" value="abc"> <input type="text" value="abc">

@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notosanskr.css);
input { width:100px; height:50px; font-family:'Noto Sans KR';}
input:nth-of-type(1) { font-weight:300; }
input:nth-of-type(2) { font-weight:400; }
input:nth-of-type(3) { font-weight:500; }
```

Test URL : https://jsfiddle.net/ze6suwys/

The result looks like this. Suddenly, only 400-weight font are rendered unusually.

[image]

```
<span>abc</span> <span>abc</span> <span>abc</span>

@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notosanskr.css);
span { font-family:'Noto Sans KR';}
span:nth-of-type(1) { font-weight:300; }
span:nth-of-type(2) { font-weight:400; }
span:nth-of-type(3) { font-weight:500; }
```

Test URL : https://jsfiddle.net/ze6suwys/2/

The result when dragging is as follows.

[image]

```
<div>abc</div> <div>abc</div> <div>abc</div>

@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notosanskr.css);
div { float:left; height:50px; margin-right:5px; border:1px solid black; font-family:'Noto Sans KR';}
div:nth-of-type(1) { font-weight:300; }
div:nth-of-type(2) { font-weight:400; }
div:nth-of-type(3) { font-weight:500; }
```

Test URL : https://jsfiddle.net/ze6suwys/4/

[image]

I'm using IE 11.125 and Windows 10. I don't know why. I wonder if it looks like that to me only. Thank you for reading it.

Comment: it looks correct to me. What about the 400-weight is incorrect to you?

Comment: @pjones235 Thank you for testing. only 400-weight font has more bottom margin, so it looks like it is aligned up. I added an example for div.

Comment: I know what you're referring to with the margin, but I don't see any issue here. I've looked on all browsers and it appears normally. I'm not sure what your exception is..

Comment: @pjones235 Since the Windows update, it seems to have found that the font rendering of applications is slightly strange (not just IE11). Thank you for your help :) (it works well in all other browsers).